# Simple 'if' statement in C not performing as expected when comparing int to char

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm new to C and have gotten stuck on something that must be very basic.

I have 2 char arrays and am calculating the absolute difference between elements of the arrays in an 'if' statement. However, the 'if' statement is not evaluated as I would expect. I am getting values printed where the difference is not greater than 1.

Is this something to do with the abs function returning an int which I then compare to a char?

Any suggestions?

```
if(abs(arr1[i] - arr2[i]) > '1')
   printf("%c ", arr1[i]);
   printf("%c ", arr2[i]);
   printf("%d diff\n", abs(arr1[i] - arr2t[i]));
```

Comment: `'1'` --> `1` ? and `arr2t` --> `arr2`

Comment: From what I see, you need `{  }` to define your `if` block, e.g. `if(abs(arr1[i] - arr2[i]) > '1') { printf("%c ", arr1[i]); printf("%c ", arr2[i]); printf("%d diff\n", abs(arr1[i] - arr2t[i])); }`??

Comment: You are aware that `'1' == 49`?

Comment: Why is it tagged c++? C and c++ are different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'1' is not same as 1. '1' is equivalent to numeral 49 from ASCII table.

So make the comparison against integer 1 in your case

```
if(abs(arr1[i] - arr2[i]) > 1)
```

Also your `if` block does not include all the lines below. Enclose the statements which need to have effect of `if` condition with `{}`.

```
if(abs(arr1[i] - arr2[i]) > 1)
{//Add braces to enclose multiple statements
   printf("%c ", arr1[i]);
   printf("%c ", arr2[i]);
   printf("%d diff\n", abs(arr1[i] - arr2[i]));// arr2t[i] -> arr2[i] seems to be a typo
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets take a look at an [ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii). The value for e.g. `'2'` is `50`, and the value for `'1'` is `49`.

Now what happens when you do `'2' - '1'`? What is the result of that? It's `1`, not `49`.

So your comparison should be against the *integer* `1` and not the character `'1'`.

---

And as mentioned, you're missing a block `{}` for the `printf` calls.

Comment: And don't forget to mention the missing block `{}` after `if()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is by comparing the int to a char.
You see, every char is displayed to the user as a char, but in the memory is represented as an int, the ASCII code of that char. 
In the same manner, you can create a char this way:

```
char c = 49;
```

and it will be the char `'1'`.

So when you compared it to the char `'1'` the compiler thinks you meant the ASCII code of the character 1, which is 49 (you can see that if you type ALT + 49 in numpad).
Just compare the result of the subtraction to the int 1 and you will be fine.